# How to Cancel a Task with a Command from WebClient

Tags: c#

Hi guys the ask in the title is the problem... i try to create a Download Manager and my problem y when try to cancel a specific download from the GUI with the ContextMenu linked to the command.

The Download Doesn't stop and i think the problem is with the token than not pass the cancelation but i dont be for why.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
XAML ContextMenu:

 <DataGrid x:Name="contenedorDescargas" Height="323" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Downloads}"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" >

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneTime}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tamaño" Width="110" Binding="{Binding Path=Size, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True ,Mode=OneWay}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Estado" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Path=State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneTime}"
                                        Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Completado" Width="150">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Value="{Binding Path=Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                </ProgressBar>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Velocidad" Width="90" Binding="{Binding Path=Speed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tiempo Restante" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=TimeLeft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Width="164" Binding="{Binding Path=Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneTime}">
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Cancelar" Command="{Binding Path=StopCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Definition of Command:

```
class StopTaskCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> action;

        public Action<object> Action
        {
            get
            {
                return action;
            }

            private set
            {
                action = value;
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public StopTaskCommand(Action<object> actionCommand)
        {
            action = actionCommand;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            action(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Implementation:

```
public class DownloadManager
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Download> downloads;
        private int id_new_task=-1;
        private ICommand stopCommand;

  public DownloadManager()
        {
            downloads = new ObservableCollection<Download>();
            StopCommand = new StopTaskCommand(StopDownload);
        }

        private void StopDownload(object obj)
        {
            Download temp = downloads.ElementAt((obj as Download).Id_task);
            temp.TokenSource.Cancel();
        }

 private void MakeTask(Download new_task, int id_task)
        {

            CancellationTokenSource cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();


            Task.Factory.StartNew((_id) =>
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                 using(var register = cancel.Token.Register(()=> client.CancelAsync()))
                {
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new_task.URI1, new_task.Name, cancel.Token);
                }


                new_task.Id_task = id_task;
                new_task.TokenSource = cancel;
                new_task.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                new_task.State = "Downloading";

                //add de object to the collection
                downloads.Add(new_task);

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (obj, send) =>
                {
                    (downloads.ElementAt(id_task) as Download).Progress = send.ProgressPercentage;
                    (downloads.ElementAt(id_task) as Download).Size = Convert.ToString(send.TotalBytesToReceive / (1024 * 1024)) + " Mb";
                    (downloads.ElementAt(id_task) as Download).Speed = string.Format("{0} Kb/s", (send.BytesReceived / 1024d / watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.0"));
                };


            },id_task,cancel.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).ContinueWith((id_t) =>
              {
                  (downloads.ElementAt(id_task) as Download).State = "Stopped";
                  (downloads.ElementAt(id_task) as Download).Speed = "0 Kb/s";

              }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

        }

    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx this may help you

Comment: Many thanks for the help @Devesh,  i found the problem! with a little more time to think